# postgres +node.js query combine

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.1

I am new to this node.js and postgres.. I am executing 2 queries(select) and i have to combie these 2 queries output into a single result. Also i have to make the 1st result to appear first and then the 2nd query.. I have the following code but i am not achieving the requirement. Also i am not sure that the code i have is correct..Suggest other idea if you have..

My code:

```
  client.query("select * from tn_village where level3 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level4 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level5 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level6 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level7 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level8 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level9 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%'",function(err,result)
    {
    client.query("select * from tn_village where level3 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level4 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level5 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level6 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level7 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level8 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level9 ILIKE '%"+village+"%'" ,function(err,result1)
    {      
    res.send(result1);
    });
    });
```

How can i combine result and result1 to a  single output..Help me to solve this..Thanks in advance..

EDIT:

```
client.query("select * from tn_village where level3 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level4 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level5 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level6 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level7 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level8 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' OR level9 ILIKE '%"+villagename+"%' ",function(err,result)
{
client.query("select * from tn_village where level3 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level4 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level5 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level6 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level7 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level8 ILIKE '%"+village+"%' OR level9 ILIKE '%"+village+"%'" ,function(err,result1)
{ 
var ret = {
            result: result,----------->if i put result1 here only the 2nd query output is showing. If i put result only 1st query output is shown..
            result1: result1
        }    


res.send(ret); 
//res.send(result1);      
});
}); 
});
```

Also i want i have doubt,that whether your code  will show output of 1st query first and then 2nd query output??

Comment: why dont you use anync.parallel ???

Comment: Thanks @sunny1304 ..I am new  to this..So i don't know deep into node.js..Anyway i will look for that..But look at @
Nick Sharp answer,if i follow that only 1 query result is returning...what's wrong in that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply following the way you have it laid out (although I prefer promises even in node for aggregating multiple async calls):

```
 client.query("select ...",function(err,result) {
    client.query("select ..." ,function(err,result1) {  
        var ret = {
            result: result,
            result1: result1
        }
        res.send(ret);
    });
 });
```

That is the simplest example I can think of to show you how easy this should be.  Now, if for example you are thinking of some sort of loop over result and result1 that will combine/munge them together etc, or if you want to concatenate the two arrays into one etc, all of that isn't clear by your question but is easy to do.

Let me know if that clarifies at all.  In essence the value of "result" is still available to you in the inner callback, so you can make use of it in your res.send.

PS - nesting calls that don't necessarily need to be nested is a bit derpy, promises or other callback aggregators would help here.

Comment: Yes I'm here, but what do you mean, is result1 null or blank, and only result is set?  Because in that case it sounds like your query for the second round might just be "bad" in that it returns no data.

Comment: Yeah in the callback of the second query you have access to both variable... so now its up to you to determine (and then clarify to us) what you want your return format to be...  It will not "show" anything, it will just return a json.  And also in your edit of course using result1 in that slot it will show the output of the second query, because that is the variable name you used in the callback of the second query.

Comment: I have to show the combined output as json, in that 1st data should be the result of first query and then 2nd..What i have to do for this??returning format be json..

Comment: Congrats man, you seemed close you just needed to step back and look it over and figure out your requirements.